# Apache Traffic Server store partial document

Tags: apache-traffic-server

https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin/faqs.en.html?highlight=partial%20content

this document says 'Traffic Server does not store partial documents in the cache.'

but, Traffic Server cache partial image(like jpg) file.
sometimes, The upper half of the image file cached.

Is there a solution?

I'm using ats 5.3.0.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "Traffic Server cache partial image(like jpg) file. sometimes"

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that ATS currently does not support storing partial objects. This is a new feature that is actively being worked on, and will hopefully be available with v6.1.0 or possibly 6.2.0.

That much said, if you see partial objects in the cache like this, you are likely experiencing one of

- Corrupted response from origin server.
- Non-conformant response from the origin (did it respond without proper headers?)
- Corrupted cache (very unlikely).